# Using Promise.all to execute a function after loop for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await

I'm trying to execute  function exportList() when loop for finished.
But function execute not waiting for the end of the cycle.
When function exportList() execute, array this.ExportList is not full.

```
 async getUser() {
  let promsArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.User.length; i++) {
    let requestUri = `domain/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='${this.User[i].login}'`;
    let prom = axios
      .get(requestUri, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        let props = {};
        let d = response.data.d;
        let department, email = "";
        if (d.UserProfileProperties.results.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < d.UserProfileProperties.results.length; i++) {
            if (d.UserProfileProperties.results[i].Key === "Department") {
              department = d.UserProfileProperties.results[i].Value;
            }
          }
        }
        props = {
          dep: department,
          email: d.Email
        };
        promsArr.push(prom);
        this.ExportList.push(props);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
 await Promise.all([promsArr]).then(this.exportList())
}
```

Comment: for a start, you're passing promArr wrong `Promise.all([promsArr])` is an array of arrays ... but secondly, the `promArr.push` is performed asynchronously - therefore the array will be empty when the code reaches `Promise.all`

Comment: the second issue is `.then` expects a function - your code is passing the result of calling a function instead

Comment: I would `promArr.push(prom)` just before the end of your for loop

Comment: and since getUser isn't returning anything - no need for `async` or `await` ... so the last 3 lines would be just `promArr.push(prom); } Promise.all(promsArr).then(() => this.exportList())`

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid writing async/await and promise functions in the same function... it makes it a little confusing to follow as you can see.

In this case I have rewritten it (not tested) as an example as how I would separate the promise generation (for parallel processing) from your async/await syntax.

```
async getUser() {
  const processResponse = function(response){
    let props = {};
    let d = response.data.d;
    let department, email = "";
    if (d.UserProfileProperties.results.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < d.UserProfileProperties.results.length; i++) {
        if (d.UserProfileProperties.results[i].Key === "Department") {
          department = d.UserProfileProperties.results[i].Value;
        }
      }
    }
    props = {
      dep: department,
      email: d.Email
    };

    return props;
  };
  const getAccountProps = function(login){ // this function returns a promise!
    let requestUri = `domain/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='${login}'`;
    return axios
      .get(requestUri, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
      })
      .then(processResponse);
  };
  try{
    let promsArr= this.User.map(u=>getAccountProps(u.login));
    let propsArr = await Promise.all(promsArr);
    this.ExportList.push(propsArr);
    await this.exportList();
  }catch(e){
    console.log('An error occurred while getting all account properties.');
  }
}
```